# Comparing distances without calculating the actual distance

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, euclidean-geometry

I'm working with a system where calculations like square roots tend to be expensive in time and introduce decimal number-related errors.

The idea is that I have a single reference 2-dimensional point, and being fed a list of hundreds of points, I need to show the closest $n$ points, but the actual distance between the points is irrelevant.

The points are always in the third quadrant $(x<0, y<0)$.

Using pythagorean distance:

$dist(a,b)=\sqrt{(x_a-x_b)^2 + (y_a-y_b)^2}$

The trivial thought of doing away with the square root and comparing the squares of the distances was a no-brainer, but I was wondering if there weren't any further simplifications I could make.

**EDIT**: I'm aware this has algorithm-related answers that could help me, but I posted here for information on the purely geometrical and numerical analysis side of things; if it still seems out of place I'll delete it.

Comment: well, depends on how "expensive" squaring calculations are.  But you can first check for $(x_i, y_i)$ if $|x_i-x| + |y_i-y| < $smallest distance.  If it isn't then it'd can't be smaller so need to check the squares.  That's *adding* a calculation, but if you have *thousands* of points that will potentially elimination multiple hundreds of square calculations.

Comment: ... in other words:  supose you have $(x_k,y_k)$ is closest so far.  Do three tests on $(x_i, y_i)$.  Are both $x_i$ closer to $x$ and $y_i$ closer to $y$ then $x_k$ and $y_k$ are?  If so, test no further, this a closer point.  If both are further, check no further, this is a further point.  Only if one is closer and the other is further do you need to check how the squares compare.  I *don't* know how expensive this is but once you've done a few dozen points, I think only a very small fraction of the remaining points will need full testing.

Comment: Well, what I *can't* answer (maybe someone else can) is that my filter will come at an initial cost (we're doing more stuff) but will eventually mean less square comparisions and I don't know when or if that becomes cost effective.  I also don't know if there are other filters as well.

Comment: Now that I think of it, this question may be better suited for [SO] since mathematically there is only _one_ way to measure distance, but practically you might be ok with cutting corners.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about algorithms and game/simulation development. Possible target for migration to [SO].

Comment: I come from there actually; It's true that the comment that helped me was of a more algorithmical nature, but I was really wondering about the calculation side of things

Comment: The alternative to a few floating point operations is multiple comparisons. conditional jumps and memory operations. It is highly unlikely that they will be faste on current hardware. If you can maintain a list of points sorted by their distance to the central point, then you have a chance. If the rest of your program could be transformed to polar coordinates, with no ill effect, then the problem evaporates. Without additional information about the overall calculation, there is next to nothing which can be done.

Comment: I ended up having a table sorted by distance and always comparing with just the furthest point and replacing in case I found something closer. It seems like there really isn't anything else that can be done outside the algorithmical side of things so I guess I'll close the question. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using squared distances is a good idea.  If your points are integers you could store a table of squares.  If the difference in one dimension is smaller than some threshold you might be able to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

There are various compromises between speed and accuracy.

Checking the square bounds between two points is fast, but not very accurate. Checking for a circle using $\sqrt{\boxed{\,}}$ is very accurate but not very fast.

You can use the famous [fast inverse sqrt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) function, or you can device a different distance procedure, like checking for an octagon instead of circle or square.

Or you can pre-compute distances to various positions in a grid and just do a lookup to the accuracy of the grid.